# Detect email client or website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, http

I am interested to detect the email client or website a new user of my site is redirected from. For instance, if he was redirected from Gmail.com (by clicking a link in one of his email there) I would like to track that.

If I need to manipulate the links leading to my website somehow I can do that.

I know there is a way to do that cause I have seen many sites and services doing it but I would like to find out how. I can track the user agent but this tells me nothing about the site or email client.

Answer (score 0):

You must use QueryStrings for this purpose. For example the link that sends the user to your site must be like this `www.yourwebsite.com/default.aspx?sender="googleMail"`

You can get this using the code shown below when your default.aspx page loads

```
    if(Request.QueryString["sender"]!=null)
{
string Sender=Request.QueryString["sender"].ToString();
}
```

You can set different Querystrings like

```
www.yourwebsite.com/default.aspx?sender="googleMail"
www.yourwebsite.com/default.aspx?sender="YahooMail"
www.yourwebsite.com/default.aspx?sender="googleAdsense"
```

There are  methods to trace the users Browser, IP address etc. But to trace this you must adopt the above method.

Comment: But how do i know if a user comes from GMail? Whether someone comes from gmail.com isn't enough (google apps allow you to read your company.com email on a gmail client)

Comment: but I think its not possible. You can know only the browser the client using.

Comment: Another option is, you can write some JavaScript codes into the email. so that you can detect the client using specific tags or something else. But placing js will be marked as spam by most of the clients and thats not advisable.